# Create a viewController or two tables in one?

Tags: ios, parsing, viewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I am parsing an XML document containing two branches from one XML document  of the same sort of item (Topics and Schools), connected by a tabBarController.

Right now, Topics is populated, but I do not know the right way to go about populating Schools:

**Should I create another viewController for School, or have some kind of conditional statement/selector sharing space with Topics in the existing viewController?**
If its the latter,  then how?

I want to do this right the first time, Please know that I know almost nothing. Thank you.

Comment: I'd consider making this question more specific; this is a little broad.

Comment: Changed it! Lemme know if you need code and if so, which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both information will be presented in the same way within a cell of the table, you should use the same viewcontroller, what will change is the datasource. You can create a custom init method with an additional type parameter which can assume the values "Topics" or "Schools" and based on this value fill the array, from xml file, with appropriate elements.